# How can I use cumsum within a group in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, cumulative-sum

I have

```py
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'id': ['A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'D', 'B', 'C'], 'val': [1,2,-3,1,5,6,-2], 'stuff':['12','23232','13','1234','3235','3236','732323']})

  id   stuff  val
0  A      12    1
1  B   23232    2
2  A      13   -3
3  C    1234    1
4  D    3235    5
5  B    3236    6
6  C  732323   -2
```

I'd like to get a running sum of `val` for each `id`, so the desired output looks like this:

```
  id   stuff  val  cumsum
0  A      12    1   1
1  B   23232    2   2
2  A      13   -3   -2
3  C    1234    1   1
4  D    3235    5   5
5  B    3236    6   8
6  C  732323   -2  -1
```

This is what I tried:

```py
df['cumsum'] = df.groupby('id').cumsum(['val'])
```

This is the error I get:

```
ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 0, placement implies 1
```

Answer (score 99, accepted):

You can call [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#transformation) and pass the [`cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cumsum.html#pandas.Series.cumsum) function to add that column to your df:

```
In [156]:
df['cumsum'] = df.groupby('id')['val'].transform(pd.Series.cumsum)
df

Out[156]:
  id   stuff  val  cumsum
0  A      12    1       1
1  B   23232    2       2
2  A      13   -3      -2
3  C    1234    1       1
4  D    3235    5       5
5  B    3236    6       8
6  C  732323   -2      -1
```

With respect to your error, you can't call `cumsum` on a Series groupby object, secondly you're passing the name of the column as a list which is meaningless.

So this works:

```
In [159]:
df.groupby('id')['val'].cumsum()

Out[159]:
0    1
1    2
2   -2
3    1
4    5
5    8
6   -1
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Hi, sorry, what is the difference between both? Is 'transform' more general and you can use whatever function?

Comment: In case you end up here to add a column "cumsum" to your dataframe, it is: `df['cumsum'] = df.groupby('id')['val'].cumsum()`

Answer (score 2):

`cumsum` is one of those functions (e.g. `cumprod`, `rank` etc.) that return a Series / dataframe that is indexed the same as the original dataframe, so all methods to supply a function to `groupby` work (and produce the same output).

All of the following are equivalent.

```py
x = df.groupby('id')['val'].agg('cumsum')
y = df.groupby('id')['val'].apply('cumsum')
z = df.groupby('id')['val'].cumsum()
w = df.groupby('id')['val'].transform('cumsum')

all(x.equals(d) for d in [y, z, w]) # True
```

Also, `df.groupby('id').cumsum()` computes the cumulative sum for all columns in `df` grouped by `'id'`.